# Sorting with MVCContrib

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, mvccontrib

Does anyone know how to sort the MVCContrib grid when using a complex object.

My grid is displaying a list of Person and I'm trying to sort on the Country property. The problem is that Country is a property an Address class which is a property of Person.

Person.Address.Country

```
    <%Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
   {
       column.For(x => x.Id);
       column.For(x => x.FirstName);
       column.For(x => x.LastName).Sortable(false);
       column.For(x => x.Address.Country).Sortable(false);
       column.For(x => x.Age).Sortable(true);
   }).Render(); %>
```

Exception: 
 
**Property 'Country' is not defined for type '{Namespace}.Person'**
var sourceProp = Expression.Property(sourceParam, this.SortBy);
\MVCContrib\UI\Grid\Sortable\ComparableSortList.cs    Line: 41

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thank you,

MG1

Answer (score 1):

A workaround would be to expose `Country` as a property on `Person` and use that:

```
public string Country { get { return Address.Country; } }
```

Answer (score 0):

@orip gave you an answer.

But if you want to use the sorting feature you need to use:

> ```
> <%Html.Grid(Model).Columns(column =>
> {
>    column.For(x => x.Id);
>    column.For(x => x.FirstName);
>    column.For(x => x.LastName).Sortable(false);
>    column.For(x => x.Address.Country).Sortable(false);
>    column.For(x => x.Age).Sortable(true);
> }).RenderUsing(new SortableHtmlTableGridRenderer<Person>())
>  .Render(); %>
> ```

Source: http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2009/02/23/rewriting-the-mvccontrib-grid-part-3-gridmodels-and-gridrenderers/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SortColumnName for this.

```
column.For(x => x.Address.Country).SortColumnName("Address.Country");
```

I have tested this and it works like a charm :)

If you are not able to access SortColumnName(), you can get the latest version of MVC contrib from 
http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/changes/7db1cecc938f